# Android emulator "New Hardware Profile" not working

Tags: android-studio, emulation

After my recent update on Android Studio, it deleted my hardware profile of emulator and also `New Hardware Profile` is not working now while creating a new emulator :/. 
When I tap "New Hardware Profile", I see a `NullPointerException: null` on the message bar of Android Studio.
Can anyone help? 
i created my app for a specific hardware and now i am not being able to work on it.

Comment: I just encountered this issue and I have sent a bug report within the Android Studio 2.1.1. What I did as a temporary workaround was to download Android 1.5.1 and create the new hardware profile using it. After that, I switched back to Android Studio 2.1.1 and used the hardware profile that I just created to create the AVD. Both versions of Android Studio can co-exist.

Comment: thanks! I plan to try that

Comment: What was the specs of your device's display btw? My error seems to indicate it can't draw the window due to a scaling issue. I have a 13.9" laptop with a whopping 3200x1800 resolution I think it's freaking out over.

Comment: It was 15" with resolution of about 700x1200. I downloaded the AS canary channel, which did not have the problem, and launched its exe and created the emulator from there. Then used that emulator from my current AS stable version.